# Difference between mongodb server data file and data folder in db for dbpath

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference between these two mongo data folders?
I have my mongod dbpath pointed to C:/data/db, however I also noticed I have a data folder in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\ which also contains indexes and collections.

Only reason I noticed this is because I got an unclean shutdown and lost 177 million docs so was trying to look closer at the issue (side note: was not able to recover even though mongo could rebuild the index for that missing collection)

Edit

Here is a log file from the server folder where I could see a dbpath pointing elsewhere

```
**aborting after fassert() failure


2018-11-18T11:40:34.164+0100 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-11-18T11:40:36.984+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'
2018-11-18T11:40:37.092+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4252 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data 64-bit host=DESKTOP-IO5LL15
2018-11-18T11:40:37.092+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-11-18T11:40:37.092+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.4
2018-11-18T11:40:37.092+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839
2018-11-18T11:40:37.092+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-11-18T11:40:37.093+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log" } }
2018-11-18T11:40:37.099+0100 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\mongod.lock is not empty.
2018-11-18T11:40:37.100+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-11-18T11:40:37.100+0100 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
```

Comment: Did you ever create a dbpath in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\  and started as  `mongod.exe --dbpath data` ?

Comment: I don't think I did but I'm not really sure. When I run mongod from the terminal in my user directory it correctly shows the C:/data/db dbpath in the terminal, however when I checked the log files in the server folder to find the unexpected shutdown error I saw that the dbpath was referenced as C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\ data which is very confusing for me. Should I reattempt to download mongodb and see if the data folder comes in this server folder?

Comment: Whats the sizes of C:/data/db and C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\ data?

Comment: C:/data/db 6.4 gb and server one is 0.4 gb

Comment: have you tried starting mongodb as `mongod.exe --dbpath C:/data/db`? Please post the errors you have about unclean shutdown

Comment: yes i tried that command you suggested, the dbpath is set to C:/data/db. Everything worked fine. I posted a section of the code about the log file in the server folder. You can see the dbpath there is different.

Comment: remove `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data\mongod.lock` this file and start the server again: `mongod.exe --dbpath C:/data/db` ?

Comment: The server works fine and I am able to upload and query data, however, my original question was to why there are 2 data files in two separate locations. This was confusing for me and I posted the question here in case someone had insight into this and knew the specificities of mongodb's folder structure

Comment: By default mongodb will start and store data into C:\data\db. But if you can start with other dbpath as well. That looks like ..Server\4.0\data. In your case it looks like you have been using a non-default location(look at the dbpath value of server log you posted)

Comment: ^^^ Exactly right. I figured it out. I was seeing some weird behavior with my database and I think it's because the dbpath was somehow pointing to two different locations and data wasn't being synced properly. I did a mongodump, uninstalled mongodb, deleted both the C:\data and C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0 folders and did a fresh install. The installation procedure specifies a data directory and a log directory in the mongo server folder. About a week ago I did an install of mongo but still had my old data/db folder and in the installation I assigned the new dbpath to the default server

Comment: ...Therefore mongo was somehow confused. Thank you for taking your time out to help me and provide feedback.

Comment: I think mongodb should fix the default data directory with the msi installer. The data path is being saved to a readable folder as well in Program Files so it makes it tough to assign the dbpath to this folder as it doesn't have write permission

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to understand why on earth mongo thinks that creating a data folder inside of Program Files would EVER be a good idea ??!!  Crazy idea.  I've just updated 3.6 (dbPath: C:\Users\user\MongoData\db) to 4.2, and its default dbPath is C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data.  crazy...